# How can add an offset to a pointer in C?

Tags: c, microcontroller, microchip

I'm modifying a microcontroller's firmware.
I have two RxBuffers and I'm planning to add a third one so I'm planning to use the same routine to parse it all of them. The problem is that one of them has a different offset from the other ones.
Example:

```
RxBuffer1="#DATA,1,5,5,8"
RxBuffer2="DATA,1,5,5,8" //<-Different offset
RxBuffer3="#DATA,1,5,5,8"

void ParseData(char *xBuffer)
{
     //Parse data starting at xBuffer +1
}
```

The `ParseData` routine was created to parse data with `RxBuffer1` format not `RxBuffer2` format.
The `#` is not used in any way at this level.
How should I pass the address to make `ParseData` get `RxBuffer2`'s address correctly?
I think should be `RxBuffer2-1`. Maybe `ParseData(RxBuffer2-1)`?

Comment: *ParseData routine was created to parse data with RxBuffer1 format not RxBuffer2 format*. Sounds like the `ParseData` should be rewritten. It should be parsing based on a delimiter rather than offsets.

Comment: *RxBuffer2-1*. I would argue that the premise of your question is not right. You should not be trying to hack the code by passing in an invalid pointer which is what `RxBuffer2-1` would seem to be. Either improve the `ParseData` function to handle both formats correctly or transform the string into the expected format before passing into the function.

Comment: @kaylum Transform the string is not an option since is a low end microcontroller that will take a lot of resources as I see it. Also I put one function as example but in the real code there is about 80 to 100 functions that processes different commands. But anyway I was thinking in to change all of them to process RxBuffer2 format and add a +1 offset for the other RxBuffers.

Answer (score 2):

It would be undefined behaviour to pass `RxBuffer2 - 1`. Instead you should make a function that expects the `RxBuffer2` format, and perhaps refactor the old function to use this new function:

```
void ParseActualData(char *xBuffer)
{
    // expects `DATA`
}

void ParseData(char *xBuffer)
{
    // expects `#DATA`
     ParseActualData(xBuffer + 1);
}
```

Or if the parsing logic permits, you could have `ParseData` accept both variants and determine what to do based on the first character (e.g. if the first character is `#` then skip it).

Comment: I put one function as example but in the real code there is about 80 to 100 functions that processes different commands. But anyway I was thinking in to change all of them to process RxBuffer2 format and add a +1 offset for the other RxBuffers. Do you think is a better approach than RxBuffer-1?

Comment: @E_Blue Yes certainly. As mentioned in my answer, `RxBuffer2 - 1` causes undefined behaviour so that is not a good solution.

Comment: @E_Blue IMHO that's not the best approach. The suggestion in this answer is better: That is, have the function handle the different formats rather than the caller of the function. There will be less code change and more robust code in the long run doing it that way. Otherwise every time the function is called the calling code needs to work out whether to adjust or not.

Comment: @M.M Thanks! Just one more question. Since I'm not fully understand how pointers works I have not clear if xBuffer should be unsigned int8 or unsigned int16. I mean, RxBuffer is defined as unsigned int8 RxBuffer1[520] but the RAM have 4KB so it need a 16 bit address.

Comment: @E_Blue I can't really help you on that one but you aren't going to be able to do "+1 byte" on a buffer of 16-bit objects

Comment: @M.M No, the objects are ASCII bytes, that's why are defined as unsigned int8. The RAM(the pointer itself) needs 16bit wide to reach all the RAM.